# how to achieve async data.. angular observable inside observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

What I am trying to achieve?

- I have multiple components having almost same checks and data manipulation.. I wanted to shift them in a observable..
- I created an observable name "getData" in my service...
- the twist is "getdata" has a if check.. ->
  if the local storage has data then return data.
  if not then request data from api call(getbyid) then manipulate it and return data..

NOTE: we can't change the getbyid(). and they both are in same service.

API

```
  getbyid(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.serverurl, id )
    .pipe(tap((res) => { return res })); 

     
  }
```

MY CODE

```
getData(origin: any, id:number):Observable<any> {
    let data= new BehaviorSubject({});
    if(origin=='main page'){
    let localstorage= this._aes.getItem('localstorage')

    if(!localstorage){  
      
      console.log('before api');
     
        this.getbyid(id).subscribe(res=>{
          console.log('res',res);
          data.next(res)
          return data
         })
      console.log('after api');
        
    }else{
      data.next({data:payload})
      return data.asObservable()
    }

    }
     
  }
```

Comment: Note: We can't change the api

Comment: Hi, sorry, but I don't get the problem what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes we can change getdata but not getbyid.

Comment: CURRENT scenario: 
 its just hitting the getbyid and not waiting for the response and proceed... 
if somehow we make it to wait for the response this can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class dataFetcher_ {
  data: BehaviorSubject;

  dataFetcher() {
    this.data = new BehaviorSubject({});
  }

  getdata(origin: any, id: number): Observable<any> {
    if (origin === 'main page') {
      const localstorage = this._aes.getItem('localstorage');

      if (!localstorage) {
        console.log('before api');

        const res = this.getbyid(id).subscribe(res => {
          console.log('res', res);
          this.data.next(res);
        });
        console.log('after api');
      } else {
        this.data.next({ data: payload });
        
      }
    }
    return this.data.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: getting empty response via this. dataFetcher_.getData('main page',0).subscribe(res=>{})
may be its because it execute return this.data.asObservable(); first.. and not waiting for the getbyid response

Comment: its just hitting the getbyid and not waiting for the response and proceed... if somehow we make it to wait for the response this can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

we need to return an observable to make it wait for the data from observable.

Reference:
[wait observable for other observable in it to respond. Angular async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422816/wait-observable-for-other-observable-in-it-to-respond-angular-async)