# wait observable for other observable in it to respond. Angular async

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10, angular11, angular12

What I am trying to achieve?

- I have multiple components having almost same checks and data manipulation.. I wanted to shift them in a observable..
- I created an observable name "getData" in my service...
- the twist is "getdata" has a if check.. ->
  if the local storage has data then return data.
  if not then request data from api call(getbyid) then manipulate it and return data..

NOTE: we can't change the getbyid(). and they both are in same service.

API

```
  getbyid(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.serverurl, id )
    .pipe(tap((res) => { return res })); 

     
  }
```

MY CODE

```
getData(origin: any, id:number):Observable<any> {
    let data= new BehaviorSubject({});
    if(origin=='main page'){
    let localstorage= this._aes.getItem('localstorage')

    if(!localstorage){  
      
      console.log('before api');
     
        this.getbyid(id).subscribe(res=>{
          console.log('res',res);
          data.next(res)
          return data.asObservable()
         })
      console.log('after api');
        
    }else{
      data.next({data:payload})
      return data.asObservable()
    }

    }
     
  }
```

CURRENT scenario: its just hitting the getbyid and not waiting for the response and proceed... if somehow we make it to wait for the response this can be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need BehaviorSubject in this kind of scenario.
Something like this should work (I supposed "payload" is the content of your storage ?):

```
  getbyid(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.serverurl, id));         
  }

  getData(origin: any, id: number): Observable<any> {
    if (origin !== 'main page') {
      return EMPTY;
    }

    const payload = this._aes.getItem('localstorage');
    return payload ? of(payload) : this.getById(id);
}
```

If `payload` is set, we return an observable with it. If not, an observable with a backend call.

In both cases, you have to subscribe from where you call `getData` method and wait response.

Comment: No problem :) ! If you could "up" the answer and mark your problem as "answered", that's be cool !

Comment: I need 15 reputation to cast a vote, but I accepted the answer.
Thanks once again.